# check if data has been loaded before passing as a prop react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an async/await api call that is made and the data is passed into my productsReducer, the problem I'm having is that the data is not loaded into the redux state when it is passed a prop into `ProductsList` and therefore throws an error when it tries to filter/map the data.

adding a check to see if it is loaded is possible in ProductsList `products && products` but I want to check on the `Main` component first if it is loaded and if so only pass this then as a prop.

I have attempted to do so with `products: state.data.products.loadng === false && state.data.products.items.data` but this always returns false

How can i check if my data is loaded before passing it as a prop?

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import styled from 'styled-components'
import ScrollToTop from '../atoms/ScrollToTop'
import Header from '../Header'
import Footer from '../Footer'
import Home from '../Home'
import * as actionCreators from './actions'
import media from '../atoms/Media'
import BreadCrumbs from '../Breadcrumbs'
import Category from '../Category'
import ProductsList from '../ProductsList'
import Product from '../Product'
import Alert from '../atoms/Alert'

import { fetchProducts } from "./actions";

import { ADD_TO_CART_E, ADD_TO_CART_P } from '../atoms/translations'    

class Main extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCategories()
    this.props.fetchSubCategories()
    this.props.fetchProducts()
  }

 handleHideAlert() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.hideAlert()
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const {alert, categories, filteredColors, filteredSizes, language, products,  showAlert, subCategories} = this.props
    const e = language === 'english'
    const p = language === 'polish'
    return(
      <Router>
        <Wrap>
        {alert && <div><Alert />{this.handleHideAlert()}</div>}
        <Header e={e} p={p} categories={categories} subCategories={subCategories} language={language} />
          {/* <BreadCrumbs /> */}
          <Route style={{ flex: 1 }} render={({ location }) =>
            <TransitionGroup>
              <CSSTransition
                key={location.key}
                timeout={500}
                classNames="page"
                mountOnEnter={true}
                unmountOnExit={true}
              >
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <MainWrap>
                  <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Home e={e} p={p} categories={categories} subCategories={subCategories} products={products} language={language} {...props} />} />
                  <Route exact path="/:catId" render={props => <Category e={e} p={p} categories={categories} subCategories={subCategories} language={language} {...props} />} />
                  <Route exact path="/:catId/:subCatId" render={props => <ProductsList  e={e} p={p} filteredColors={filteredColors} filteredSizes={filteredSizes} categories={categories} subCategories={subCategories} products={products} language={language} {...props} />} />
                  <Route exact path="/:catId/:subCatId/:productId" render={props => <Product categories={categories} subCategories={subCategories} products={products} showAlert={showAlert} language={language} {...props} />} />
                  </MainWrap>
                </Switch>
              </CSSTransition>
            </TransitionGroup>
          } />
          {console.log('products',products)}
  { e ? ADD_TO_CART_E : ADD_TO_CART_P}
          <Footer />
        </Wrap>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  alert: state.ui.alert,
  language: state.language,
  categories: state.data.categories.categories,
  subCategories: state.data.subCategories.subCategories,
  products: state.data.products.loadng === false && state.data.products.items.data 
  productsLoading: state.data.products.loadng,
  filteredColors: state.filters.colors,
  filteredSizes: state.filters.sizes
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Main);
```

**productsReducer.js**

```
  import {
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE
  } from '../../Constants'

  const initialState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null
        };

      case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          items: action.payload
        };

      case FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload.error,
          items: []
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

**productsList.js**

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { e, p, filteredColors, filteredSizes,  match, products } = this.props
    const productFilter = products && products.filter(products =>
      (
        (filteredColors.length >= 1 && filteredSizes.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredColors.includes(products.color) ||
        (filteredSizes.length >= 1 && filteredColors.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredSizes.includes(products.size) ||

        (filteredSizes.length >= 1 && filteredColors.length >= 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId) && filteredColors.includes(products.color) && filteredSizes.includes(products.size)) ||
        (filteredSizes.length < 1 && filteredColors.length < 1 && products.cat === match.params.subCatId)
      )
    return(
      <Section>
        <Container>
          <Grid>
            {console.log(productFilter)}

            {productFilter && productFilter.map(filteredProduct =>
              <Cell key={filteredProduct.id}>
                <ProductListCard e={e} p={p} match={match} {...filteredProduct} />
              </Cell>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
        <Filters>
          <Filter />
        </Filters>
      </Section>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  filteredProducts: state.filteredProducts
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(ProductsList);
```

Comment: you're passing `state.data.products.items.data` as a prop but `items` in the reducer is an array and not an object with a `data` key, you should pass the `items` instead of `items.data` like : `products: state.data.products.loading ? [] : state.data.products.items`

Comment: thanks for spotting the typo, @Taki your right , this fixes the error but now I'm not sure how to acces the array in data?

Comment: ok I removed the curly braces around `{data}` in the api call and now the data is an array and works correctly

Answer (score 1):

You could set the initial state as loading is true. In the constructor of the component or in the reducer. In the render function of `Main.js` check if the loading state is true and make sure to render something like a loading component.

When the data is loading set the loading state to false. The page will rerender and render the list with the data. Is this enough or would you like an example?